# Disable NIC interface permanently in RHEL7

Tags: linux

How to disable NIC interface permanently in RHEL7? "ifconfig -a" should not show an interface after disabling?

Any idea please?

Comment: Find the drivername with `ethtool -i <device-name>`, then unload the module `modprobe -r <driver-name>`.

Comment: ^ Don't do that. that will only remove the module from the kernel ephemerally (it'll reset on boot) and removing modules to turn off NICs will turn off every NIC that uses that driver. Also @Thomas don't put answers in comments. This subverts the quality control system.

Comment: What’s the reason for this request? Is this a physical server or virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by a simple lack of configuration. How this is accomplished will be determined by whether you use NetworkManager or traditional ifupdown. All you're wanting is to not have an IP address on the NIC in question, and you can accomplish this by not giving it one. I'll give a solution for traditional networking, as I have opinions about NetworkManager.

The configuration for each NIC is stored in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` under files named like `ifcfg-eth0`. These are the files in which you'll put line-by-line configuration options. Below is an example of a NIC that will not try to obtain an IP via DHCP, or have an IP assigned to it statically via the "address=" field (not listed, because we aren't giving it an address)

Prior to making these modifications, you'll want to use the existing configuration to take the NIC down. This can be accomplished via `ifdown eth0`. I'm assuming the NIC you want is eth0, but you haven't specified which one you'd like to disable. The names can be of many forms, so tune to taste.

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO=none # note here that "none" will disable DHCP
NM_CONTROLLED="no" #This prevents NetworkManager from controlling this interface, honoring only the config elements in this file
PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT=1 #Irrelevant in the absence of DHCP
ONBOOT="yes" # You could change this to "no" to prevent the interface from coming up even at layer 2
TYPE=Ethernet
DEFROUTE=yes #Irrelevant in the absence of DHCP
PEERDNS=yes #Irrelevant in the absence of DHCP
PEERROUTES=yes #Irrelevant in the absence of DHCP
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes #Irrelevant if you're not even giving it an IPv4 address
IPV6INIT=no # Change this to "no" to prevent from getting an IPv6 address
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME="eth0"
```

After you're done with that configuration, you can issue `ifup eth0` to see if your configuration does what you want it to.